# Highstock charts fails in remote but no in local

Tags: php, jquery, mongodb, laravel, highcharts

I have a MongoDB database with Laravel in Backend, I get the data from mongo and I out in to the highcharts, in Local it looks good:

[image]

But in remote with the same code looks like this:

[image]

And the console shows me the next error:

```
(14) highstock.js:8 Highcharts error #15: www.highcharts.com/errors/15

(8) highstock.js:8 Highcharts error #15: www.highcharts.com/errors/15
```

It's the same code, the same version of mongodb the sambe version of PHP driver:S

**EDIT:**

The jQuery code that I have:

```
$('#historic-graph').highcharts('StockChart', {


                rangeSelector: {

                    selected: 1

                },



                title: {

                    text: 'Gráfico Histórico'

                },



                series: [{

                    name: 'Dato',

                    data: data,

                    tooltip: {

                        valueDecimals: 2

                    }

                }]



            });
```

And the Data that I recieve:

```
[[1455839004000,130],[1455839006000,130],[1455839008000,133],[1455839011000,134],[1455839013000,133],[1455839015000,132],[1455839017000,134],[1455839020000,130],[1455839022000,134],[1455839024000,133],[1455839027000,134],[1455839029000,131],[1455839031000,134],[1455839034000,132],[1455839036000,130],[1455839038000,132],[1455839040000,134],[1455839043000,132],[1455839045000,133],[1455839047000,130]]
```

[TIME, VALUE]

The time is **strtotime created_at * 1000** with php.

**EDIT 2:**

PHP code that I return with data variable in jQuery after ajax request:

```
foreach ($alldata as $item) {
                $date = new Carbon($item['created_at']);
                $date = $date->addHours(Auth::user()->utc)->timestamp * 1000;
                array_push($data, array($date, floatval(round($item['value'], 2))));
            }
```

I add an hour for users UTC timezone.

Comment: That means you data is not sorted ascending by `x` values. Make sure that initial data is sorted (`myData.sort(function (a, b) { return a.x - b.x; });`)

Comment: Hey Pawel, thanks for you response, with the code that I have (I put the code in the post) how can I edit the data sort?

Comment: Change that: `data: data,` -> `data: data.sort(function (a, b) { return a.x - b.x; }),`

Comment: I have the same problem:S

Comment: For me it works fine, see: http://jsfiddle.net/sz0esszz/5/ And I don't see any error.

Comment: Yes, and in local it works fine but I have a remote server and you see the image result. Look at EDIT 2, the php code that I use, maybe that is the problem?

Comment: Could you show data that **produces** that error? I mean, error comes exactly from data, so maybe your data is somehow corrupted?